# Why aren't my values in my for loops appending properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

my values from my for loop are not appending. They only include one of the values found in the list. I have tried several different indentation levels, but that did not seem to work.

Here is the code:

```py
def compute_wind_chill(temp1,temp2) :
    celcius_list = []
    for celcius in range(temp1,temp2 + 1) :
        fahrenheit_list = []
        if celcius <= temp2 :
            fahrenheit = (celcius * 9 / 5) + 32
            celcius += 1
        fahrenheit_list.append(fahrenheit)
        celcius_list.append(celcius)
        for fahrenheit in list(fahrenheit_list) :
            wind_chill = 0
            wind_speed = 5
            five_mph_wind = []
            if fahrenheit <= max(fahrenheit_list) :
                wind_chill = 35.74 + (0.6215 * fahrenheit) - (35.75 * (wind_speed ** 0.16)) + (0.4275 * fahrenheit * (wind_speed ** 0.16))
                if fahrenheit > 50 :
                    wind_chill = 'X'
                fahrenheit += 5/9
            five_mph_wind.append(wind_chill)
    table = [celcius_list, fahrenheit_list, five_mph_wind]
    for a in zip(*table):
        print(*a)
```

`temp1` and `temp2` are values input by the user.

Could anyone explain why it is doing this?

```py
compute_wind_chill(-10, 5)
# Outputs -9 41.0 37.64696367457145
```

The expected output should include -10, -9, -8, etc.

Comment: You are setting `five_mph_wind = []` inside your inner for loop, which will mean the list only has one element at the time the outer loop (across the temp range) finishes. When you zip the lists they will be unequal length and therefore some results are truncated.

Comment: @maximus Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moving the `fahrenheit_list = []` and `five_mph_wind = []` to the outer scope fixed it for me

```py
def compute_wind_chill(temp1,temp2) :
    celcius_list = []
    fahrenheit_list = []
    five_mph_wind = []
    for celcius in range(temp1,temp2 + 1) :
        if celcius <= temp2 :
            fahrenheit = (celcius * 9 / 5) + 32
            celcius += 1
        fahrenheit_list.append(fahrenheit)
        celcius_list.append(celcius)
        for fahrenheit in list(fahrenheit_list) :
            wind_chill = 0
            wind_speed = 5
            if fahrenheit <= max(fahrenheit_list) :
                wind_chill = 35.74 + (0.6215 * fahrenheit) - (35.75 * (wind_speed ** 0.16)) + (0.4275 * fahrenheit * (wind_speed ** 0.16))
                if fahrenheit > 50 :
                    wind_chill = 'X'
                fahrenheit += 5/9
            five_mph_wind.append(wind_chill)
    table = [celcius_list, fahrenheit_list, five_mph_wind]
    for a in zip(*table):
        print(*a)

compute_wind_chill(-10,5)
```

Output:

```
-9 14.0 5.93387563581391
-8 15.8 5.93387563581391
-7 17.6 8.048081505064417
-6 19.4 5.93387563581391
-5 21.2 8.048081505064417
-4 23.0 10.162287374314916
-3 24.8 5.93387563581391
-2 26.6 8.048081505064417
-1 28.4 10.162287374314916
0 30.2 12.276493243565415
1 32.0 5.93387563581391
2 33.8 8.048081505064417
3 35.6 10.162287374314916
4 37.4 12.276493243565415
5 39.2 14.39069911281592
6 41.0 5.93387563581391
```